# Does Tor prevent people from finding the sites you visited before dowloading Tor, or does it only block your history after downloading Tor?

Tags: onion-services, security, browsers

The title is my question--does Tor block access to your internet browsing history before you download Tor, or does it block access to your internet use after downloading Tor?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what your question is about. Before you download Tor (or Tor Browser) is does not do anything. When you have downloaded Tor Browser and use it, it will block access to your browsing history and delete it every time when you close the browser. I'm also not sure what you mean with the second part of your question. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Tor Browser here. Tor Browser itself doesn't keep a history of the pages you visited. If it comes to any pages you visit using other browsers, Tor Browser does not try to stop them from storing any history.

If you used another browser for browsing or to download Tor Browser, that history is not removed.